Is there an "other action" button in staging ground like review queue?
Just hopped into the staging ground review queue and saw a non-English post be reviewed and suggested a major change by someone else.
I figured I can upvote that suggested major change. However, I'm not sure what should be done next. Should I just click on skip? Or is there an action representing "Other action" as in the review queue? Or should I choose the Require Major changes option again? I did not found relevant guidance in Staging Ground Workflow: Question Details & Actions as well.



if there's no additional action to take, then skip. it doesn't need additional "votes" for requires major changes

@KevinB So the require major change button shouldn't be chosen again right?

Not unless you feel a second comment is needed, though, in that case as well you could just leave the comment instead.

Also in most cases you don't need to review posts with a Major Changes label as these require changes from the author and not action from reviewers. Just look for posts that are New or in Re-Evaluate (you can use the Status filter for this).
